# Editar um arquivo txt c#

Tags: c#

Esse codigo abaixo eh um arquivo de configuração `.ini`

Como eu faço pra ler a linha X e editar 0 ou 1, no app fiz tudo como `checkbox`, se `check = 1` se `false = 0`, porém, nao sei como fazer ler essas linhas e pegar somente a parte configurável q seria 0 ou 1 ...

alguem pode me ajudar?

```html
[AntiLag]
DisableStaticEffect = 0
DisableDynamicEffect = 0
DisableSkillEffect = 0
DisableGlowEffect = 0

[Graphics]
Anisotropy = 1
MaxAnisotropy = 32
Linear  = 1
Fog             =       1
TronEffects     =       1
MiniMap  = 1

[Other]
ServerTime = 2
DisablePing = 0
```

Comment: Tem essa lib aq que ajuda bastante: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

Comment: irei ver aqui, obrigado.